# JMSException: CWSIA0005E: The JCA runtime failed to create a connection

Tags: java, multithreading, jms, connection-pooling, websphere-8

I am getting below two exceptions while publishing messages (50 messages at a time) in queue. I'm using ThreadLocal(includes JMS publishing class also) in my project.
I really don't have any clue why this occurs. Any help to move further is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
Exception:javax.jms.JMSException: CWSIA0024E: The JCA runtime failed to create a session.          
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsConnectionImpl.createJcaSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:951)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueConnectionImpl.createQueueSession(JmsQueueConnectionImpl.java:115)
          ...
          ...
  Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180001
         at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1721)
         at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3321)
         at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2567)
         at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1544)
         at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1027)
         at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsJcaConnectionImpl.java:394)
         at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsConnectionImpl.createJcaSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:946)

Exception:javax.jms.JMSException: CWSIA0005E: The JCA runtime failed to create a connection
   ...
```

Code to publish::

```
try {
        QueueConnectionFactory queueFactory = null;
        queueFactory = getQueueConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactoryJNDIName);
        // Create a QueueConnection
        queueConnection = queueFactory.createQueueConnection();
        try {
                // Create a QueueSession
                queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true,   Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Queue queue = getQueue(queueJNDIName);                  
                // Create the Publisher
                queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
                // Create a message
                ObjectMessage objMsg = queueSession.createObjectMessage(object);
                // Publish the message
                queueSender.send(object);
                // Commit the session
                queueSession.commit();

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                throw e;
        } finally {
                try {
                    // Close the QueueSender
                    if (null != queueSender) {
                        queueSender.close();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                        throw e;
                }
                try {
                    // Close the Queue Session
                    if (null != queueSession) {
                        queueSession.close();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
                try {
                    // Close the QueueConnection
                    if (null != queueConnection) {
                        queueConnection.close();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

**Configurations :**

- Server                 : Websphere 8.5.5
- Connection timeout     : 300sec
- Maximum connections    : 50
- Unused timeout         : 1800sec
- Purge policy           : EntirePool

Comment: Can you post some code? Otherwise it's difficult to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Do verify by clicking on Test Connect from the Websphere Admin console where you have defined the connection.

Comment: @mdnghtblue, thanks for your reply. I have added code. Hope this might help. Not both exceptions occur at same time. For few msges its CWSIA0024E and rest CWSIA0005E.

Answer (score 0):

It was `ThreadLocal` that was the cause of the issue. Setting `ThreadLocal` at start did not resolve it. The issue was fixed after removing `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately i forgot my old login mail id. So, logged in using my latest. Still answer remains same.